# Retrieving an RDS endpoint from within USER DATA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a single MySQL RDS instance and an AMI containing a Grails application. I would like to use the User Data function to populate the Grails application.yml file with the RDS endpoint. How do I retrieve RDS the endpoint from within User Data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to use User Data:

- **Just as data:** The contents of User Data is accessible via `http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data/`, so your application could just parse the contents and do what you wish with it.
- **As an executable script:** On Linux, starting User Data with `#!` will cause it to be executed, so you could write a script to update the `application.yml` file.

An alternate concept would be to store the RDS Endpoint in the **AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store**. Then, use a User Data script to extract it from there and store it in `application.yml`. This way, the endpoint can be easily updated in Parameter Store without modifying any scripts.

Answer (score 0):

User Data is nothing but shell script while runing on Linux AMI. 
You can edit appication.yml file using shell script and add you parameters.

Comment: I have tried to create a script that retrieves the endpoint and updated the application.yml file but when it executes it is replacing the current endpoint with nothing (ie. blank). Any idea why? This is the current script: 
              
              `#!/bin/bash
              RDS=aws rds --region eu-west-2 describe-db-instances --query 
              "DBInstances[*].Endpoint.Address" --output text
              sudo sed -i "s/CURRENT_RDS_ENDPOINT/${RDS}/g" 
              pathtofile/application.yml`